# Windows Universal App windows 10 menu

Tags: c#, windows

I am creating a Windows universal app but can't find out how to create a menu like you can find in the groove music app on windows phone 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create menus like these with the Splitview control. It was introduced with Windows 10. See Docs here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.splitview.aspx

Little hint: The Button on the upper left to show and hide the menu is not part of the Splitview control and has to be created manually.

You can find this Menu in several samples including mine on github:
github.com/DanielMeixner/w10demoking/

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this awesome tutorial from Jerry Nixon:

[Implementing an Awesome Hamburger Button with XAML’s new SplitView control in Windows 10](https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=BE501A3A7A1041AE&resid=BE501A3A7A1041AE!26606&authkey=AB6bQksS2a4fioE)